Unable to fetch the CLI MOTD and remote config - firebase hosting issue
I am having trouble with deploying my webapp. When I run
firebase deploy --only hosting

which is how I normally host my webapp, I now get an error saying:
!  Unable to fetch the CLI MOTD and remote config. This is not a fatal error, but may indicate an issue with your network connection.

Error: Assertion failed: resolving hosting target of a site with no site name or target name. This should have caused an error earlier

I haven't gotten this issue before.
I tried to run npm install -g firebase-tools as suggested here. I've also tried running firebase login --debug, but I am successfully logged in.
Does anyone know what I need to do to resolve it?
Thank you so much for any assistance!
